# PHP avatar not being put in folder?

Tags: php

My server goes, /var/www/html/uploads. I tried putting some before uploads and they didn't seem to be working.

```
if ($_FILES['photo']['name']) {
         $valid_file = true;
         if (!$_FILES['photo']['error']) {

              $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photo']['name']);
              $pathImage = SITE_ROOT . '/uploads/' . $new_file_name;
              if ($_FILES['photo']['size'] > (1024000)) { // Maximum 1MB 
              image
                   $valid_file = false;
                   $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
              }

              if ($valid_file) {
                   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $pathImage);
```

Comment: Check in your script for errors with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and also check if your folder has `755` or `777` rights

Comment: Check your path once `$pathImage` if it is correct path or not.

Comment: What rights should the folder have?

Comment: See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) for your rights info.

Comment: This is the path in the server "/var/www/html/uploads", I changed it to that and still doesn't work.